# AttributeError response object has no attribute selector

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am coming with new question. The last one (and my first one) was very well answered. Now I have AttributeError. It happens during crawling. Output is below. I wonder how it happens because my code is by the book, directly from Scrapy official tutorial. What is happening? Thank you again!

```
2015-08-14 11:36:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.adacta.si/images/en/CP-Suite-Brochure.pdf> (referer: http://www.adacta.si/storitve/podpora-procesu-planiranja)
2015-08-14 11:36:39 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.adacta.si/images/en/CP-Suite-Brochure.pdf> (referer: http://www.adacta.si/storitve/podpora-procesu-planiranja)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "E:\analitika\SURS\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\job_spider.py", line 25, in
parse
    response.selector.remove_namespaces()
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'selector'


#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding=UTF-8  
import scrapy, urlparse, os
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import JobItem
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin
from datetime import datetime


class JobSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    #allowed_domains = ["www.aclovse.si"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.adacta.si"]

    #Check list, that helps us to avoid duplication of results.
    jobs_urls = []


    def parse(self, response):

        response.selector.remove_namespaces() 

        #We choose all urls, they are defined by "href". 
        #These are either webpages on our website either new websites.
        urls = response.xpath('//@href').extract()
        #... and so on
```

Comment: The thing is that sometimes I get this error and sometimes not. I guess it is up to the url ?

Comment: First of all, if you have additions to your question it's more approprate to edit the question (a grey link below the question and it's tags) instead of adding a comment. Second you will have to show where you get `response` from (ie what type it is).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by parsing this? Do you want to download these PDF files?

Comment: Hi, thank you for notice about editing @skyking. I am just recursively following all webpages on certain enterprise website and trying to find one specific webpage with job vacancies information. I am sorry, now I see that is PDF. I don't need that PDF. I guess in the case, when I find PDF, I should just ignore in and don't add it to crawl list. What is the best way ?